# Oracle Regular Expression - find all values in text

Tags: regex, oracle

I have a text:

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit {amet} augue egestas blandit, quam. Phasellus vitae arcu dolor, scelerisque vel, purus. Aliquam id {nulla} luctus et lacus quis neque. Nam {enim}. Etiam tincidunt tempus. Quisque adipiscing iaculis"

some words are enclosed in brackets, Question how to get a list of all the words in parentheses?

I would expect a result:

```
"amet"
"nulla"
"enim"
```

I tried using the regular expression REGEXP_SUBSTR, but I can only retrieve one word (the nth element). How to fetch all the words where the number of words in brackets can be different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need regular expressions, you can do it using simple (and faster) string functions (`INSTR` and `SUBSTR`) in a recursive sub-query factoring clause:

```sql
WITH bounds ( value, start_pos, end_pos ) AS (
  SELECT value,
         INSTR(value, '{', 1),
         CASE INSTR(value, '{', 1)
         WHEN 0
         THEN 0
         ELSE INSTR(value, '}', INSTR(value, '{', 1) + 1)
         END
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT value,
         INSTR(value, '{', end_pos + 1),
         CASE INSTR(value, '{', end_pos + 1)
         WHEN 0
         THEN 0
         ELSE INSTR(value, '}', INSTR(value, '{', end_pos + 1) + 1)
         END
  FROM   bounds
  WHERE  start_pos > 0
  AND    end_pos > 0
)
SELECT SUBSTR( value, start_pos + 1, end_pos - start_pos - 1 ) AS str
FROM   bounds
WHERE  start_pos > 0
AND    end_pos > 0;
```

If you really want to use (slower) regular expressions then:

```sql
SELECT str
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS APPLY (
         SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '\{(.*?)\}', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 1) AS str
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(value, '\{(.*?)\}')
       )
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value ) AS
SELECT 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit {amet} augue egestas blandit, quam. Phasellus vitae arcu dolor, scelerisque vel, purus. Aliquam id {nulla} luctus et lacus quis neque. Nam {enim}. Etiam tincidunt tempus. Quisque adipiscing iaculis' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> | STR |
> | --- |
> | amet |
> | nulla |
> | enim |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=cbb5e2621f6130ac0c61ab70a3694e51)*

Comment: Ah, yes - recursive CTE. Nice, as well as regexp! I was trying to use REGEXP_REPLACE and miserably failed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not smart enough to do it with SQL (regexp included). But, if you don't have anything better, see whether a function helps.

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test (par_str in varchar2) return sys.odcivarchar2list is
  2    retval sys.odcivarchar2list := sys.odcivarchar2list();
  3    l_str  varchar2(20);
  4  begin
  5    for i in 1 .. (regexp_count(par_str, '{') / 2) + 1 loop
  6      l_str := substr(par_str, instr(par_str, '{', 1, i) + 1,
  7                               instr(par_str, '}', 1, i) - instr(par_str, '{', 1, i) - 1
  8                     );
  9      retval.extend;
 10      retval(i) := l_str;
 11    end loop;
 12    return retval;
 13  end;
 14  /

Function created.

SQL>
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select * from table(f_test('&col'));
Enter value for col: Lorem ipsum dolor sit {amet} augue egestas blandit, quam. Phasellus vitae arcu dolor, scelerisque vel, purus. Aliq
uam id {nulla} luctus et lacus quis neque. Nam {enim}. Etiam tincidunt tempus.

COLUMN_VALUE
------------------------------------------------------------
amet
nulla
enim

SQL>
```

Comment: such a solution as a last resort - I could do it myself;) I'm waiting for regular expressions. Somewhere I saw such a query with a regular expression based on select with the "connect" clause, but I can not find it